# Finding minimal ratio of $AB/BO$

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry, ratio

A line passes through the origin $O$ and cut the parabola $y=-\frac{x^2}{2}+1$ at point B in the first quarter, and also cut the line $y=-x+2$ at point $A$.

Need to find points $A,B$ so that the ration $\frac{AB}{BO}$ will be minimal. Also need to find the equation of that line.

I called my line $y=mx+n$.
Then $A(x,-x+2), B(t,-\frac{t^2}{2}+1)$.
Then by the distance formula I got

$$f^2=\frac{(-x+2+\frac{t^2}{2}-1)^2+(x-t)^2}{(\frac{t^2}{2}-1)^2+t^2}$$

But I have too many letters here, don't know how to get out of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Since the line goes through the origin, $n = 0$. Also $A(x,-x+\mathbf{2})$ and $B(t,-t^2/2 + \mathbf{1})$.

Comment: Still I have $x,t$, and thanks I put that in my attempt.

Comment: Note that both points go through $y = mx$, that means that $$\frac{-t^2/2 + 1}{t} = \frac{-x+2}{x} = m$$
Write $x$ and $t$ in terms of $m$ and you'll only have one variable.

Comment: You don't need to use the distance formula. It would be sufficient to consider the ratio of the $x$ components (or $y$ components) of AB and OB

Comment: I didn't understand why it is sufficient, and I found by Darth help, $x$ in terms of $t$ but I got an equation with $5th$ degree..

Comment: The ratio will give me the connection but I need the min ration of the lengths, so I have to use eventually the distance formula.

Comment: resort to polar coordinates

Comment: We didn't learn polar coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the line through the origin be $y=mx$ and let $m=\tan\theta$. From the data given, at B the $x$ component is $-m+\sqrt{m^2+2}=p$ and at A the $x$ component is $\frac{2}{m+1}=q$.

The ratio $$\frac{AB}{OB}=\frac{AB\cos\theta}{OB\cos\theta}$$, so it is sufficient to consider the ratio of the $x$ components $\frac{q-p}{p}=\frac qp-1$

This will be minimum when the quantity $$R=\frac pq=\frac 12(m+1)(-m+\sqrt{m^2+2})$$ is maximum.

Considering $\frac{dR}{dm}=0$, and a bit of algebra which reduces very easily, we end up with $$m=\frac 12$$

Comment: We only learn the connection of $\tan\theta=m$,can you explain why $AB=\cos\theta AB$?, and why from that it's sufficient to consider the ratio of the $x$ components.

Comment: karen use $cos\theta$ as ratio of Adjacent to hypotenuse in a right triangle

Comment: Which triangle? I'd appreciate if one can explain from that step.

Comment: $AB\cos\theta=q-p$ in the triangle formed by drawing vertical and horizontal lines through A and B and whose hypotenuse is AB. Likewise, $OB\cos\theta=p$